# He has been watching TV

Tags: grammar

1.He has been watching TV.

What does this sentence mean?

Does it mean that the person started watching TV sometime before and still watching it or the person started watching TV sometime before and has stopped watching it?
does it mean something else rather than my options?

Comment: This question is more suitable for the ELL (English Language Learners) site.

Comment: Hi, Vinnie, please read the link that I posted in the above comment. As @ab2 mentioned, I'd like to advise you to visit our sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), but please make sure you take the [tour](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit their [Help Center](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) before posting any question. Good luck.

Comment: Same question was posted on ELL, [He has been watching TV](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/79059/he-has-been-watching-tv).

Answer (score 0):

The first option is right. It means that the person has started sometime before and is still watching TV. The continuous perfect tense is often used to indicate that the action has been performed for a long time (most often longer than it's supposed to).

Comment: Hi, user149411. Welcome to EL&U. The present perfect continuous (progressive) doesn't necessarily indicate that the action has been performed for a long time. Please make sure that you take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Comment: It's not necessarily true that he is still watching TV.

Comment: @reinierpost doesn't it mean that the person is watching TV now?

Comment: I don't think I'm stretching the meaning of the sentence too far by suggesting the person being spoken of has a "certain look" about him which says to me, "Boy, he sure looks as though he's been watching TV. His eyes are bleary, and he's walking like a zombie!"  In other words, his TV-watching is in the past; it has stopped; and now he evinces a certain zombie-like appearance! Don

Comment: Just google for examples. See e.g. [this Calvin & Hobbes](http://www.gocomics.com/calvinandhobbes/1993/05/08) strip, where Calvin's father says to Calvin: *"You've been watching athletic shoe ads again, haven't you?"*

Answer (score -3):

That's mean the person started watching TV sometime before and still watching it now.

Comment: No. Usually, the person is *not* watching it now. When a BBC voiceover says: "You've been watching *(some programme)*", you are *not* watching that programme.